# Check all post values = yes and are not empty

Tags: php

I have a form which has a load of radio buttons posting yes/no answers.  Id like to check they're all YES and NOT empty.

```
session_start();

if($_POST["minRequirementsForm"] == '1') {
     foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        if ($value == 'no') {  
            $error = 1; 
        } else { 
            $error = 2; 
        }   
     }
}
```

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I tried ISSET AND EMPTY and none of them worked.

Comment: Impossible, unless you build an array with name of radio buttons name, iterate the array and compare against $_POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are getting the post values correctly, the flaw is in your logic.

You are saying

```
If the value is no
    Error = 1
Else If the value is yes
    Error = 2
```

Meaning that a yes after a no will set error = 2.

You probably want

```
$required_fields = array("radio1" => NULL, "radio2" => NULL, "radio3" => NULL);
if($_POST["minRequirementsForm"] == '1') {
    $error = 2;
     foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        if ($value == 'no') {  
            $error = 1; 
        }
        if (array_key_exists($key, $required_fields))
        {
             unset($required_fields[$key]);
        }
     }
    if (count($required_fields) > 0)
    {
         $error = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Radio buttons are supposed to have a value in them.  If you wish to check that all have been submitted, you will need a matching array on the server side of all the fields that require a value, since they will not be in the $_POST array if they don't contain a value.

Comment: Ill use your code mate thanks.  Ill stick a default value in there.

Comment: Just edited it to show you how you would do the array comparison method.

Comment: Thats cool thank you for your help...ill store that little snippet :)